# How to add catch block to existing try catch block in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

[IntelliJ workspace snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cAxq.png)

I am new to IntelliJ IDE. I was working with eclipse previously and moving to IntelliJ. In eclipse if there is a new exception for a code in an existing try-catch block, an error is red-underlined. If we right click the error, there is an option to add the respective catch block in the existing try-catch block. Is there anything similar in the IntelliJ too ?

Comment: Yes. Put the cursor on the code with the red squiggly line, and hit Alt-Enter, and it will always give you suggestions on how to fix errors.

Comment: @JBNizet perfect ... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the cursor on the error. Press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  and select any one of the following suggestions `Add 'catch' clause` or `Add exception to existing catch clause`